# GA4 Landing Page Report only shows Not Set

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Google Analytics 4, my Reports>Engagement>Landing Page shows only one row which says "Not Set".  I realize that if an event fires before the Page View that might trigger this for some pages.  However, I'm not seeing any other pages - only Not Set.  If I click on the + to add another column such as "page path and screen type", it is broken down by URL, which is similar to the Pages Report in Universal GA.

In my Admin>Data Streams>Enhanced Measurement, Page Views is enabled, so I would expect Landing Pages to be populated.  I've seen several articles suggest modifying an existing report and adding "Landing Page+query string" but that has the same result.

Does GA4 not track landing pages as part of it's page views?  What gives?  All I really want is the Universal GA Landing Pages report.